# pH of 0.5M K2CO3

Tags: acid-base

$\ce{H2CO3}$ ionises as 
\begin{align}
\ce{H2CO3 + H2O &<=> H3O+ + HCO3-}  & K_\mathrm a &= \pu{4.0*10^{-7}}\\
\ce{HCO3- + H2O &<=> H3O+ + CO3^2-} & K_\mathrm a &= \pu{5*10^{-11}}\\
\end{align}

The question is to find out the $\mathrm{pH}$ of $\pu{0.5 M}$  $\ce{K2CO3}$ solution.

Since $\ce{K2CO3}$ is a salt of weak acid and strong base hence its pH is given by 
$$\mathrm{pH} = \frac{\mathrm pK_\mathrm w + \mathrm pK_\mathrm a + \log c}{2}.$$

I am unsure of which $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ I should consider. Any help shall be appreciated.

Comment: Consider obtaining $K_{\mathrm{b}}$ and solving equilibrium from the perspective of base.

Comment: @Zhe we are given $K_a$ and not $K_b$. I think there will be anionic hydrolysis of the salt.

Comment: $\mathrm{K}_{b}$ of the conjugate base is $\mathrm{K}_{a}$ of the acid.

Comment: @Zhe i know that $K_b$ of conjugate base is $K_a$ of acid but couldnot infer anything from this. can you please elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: $$\ce{CO3^{2-} + H2O <=> OH- + HCO3-},\ K_{\mathrm{b}} = ?$$

Comment: The second equilibria has little effect on your calculation, so you would be fine ignoring it, but if you want to be completely accurate, see here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/50894/15410

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write down the actual (equilibrium) reaction that develops between carbonate ion and water when one proton is exchanged (only full-fledged strong acids or bases might exchange a second proton to any significant extent).  Which conjugate acid/base appears?  $\ce {H2CO3/HCO3-}$ or $\ce {HCO3-/CO3^{2-}}$?  When you see which one it is, use that dissociation constant.

Answer (score 0):

The  carbonate ion is the Conjugate base of the weak acid 
$\ce{HCO_3^-}\ (K_{a(HCO_3^-)}={5\times10^{-11}})$, so this solution will alkaline. Given the concentration of this solution ,the pH should be sufficiently high to preclude the formation of any significant amount of $\ce{H_2CO_3}$ , so the solution of this problem as a solution of a monoprotic weak base:
$\ce{CO_3^{-2} + H_2O <=> HCO_3^-  + OH^-}$
$$\ce{K_{b(CO_3^{-2})}}=\frac{[OH^-][HCO_3^-]}{[CO_3^{-2}]} =\frac{K_w}{K_{a(HCO_3^-)}}=\frac{10^{-14}}{5\times 10^{-11}}=\ce{2\times10^{-4}}$$
Neglecting the $\ce{OH^-}$ produced by the autoprotolysis of water, it is valid to make the usual assumption that $\ce{[OH^-]}={[HCO_3^-]}$,and little of the carbonate goes to bicarbonate,so$\ce{[CO_3^{-2}]}={[CO_3^{-2}]_0}=0.5$ ,so thus
  $$\dfrac{[OH^-]^2}{0.5}=K_{b(CO_3^{-2})}= \ce{2\times10^{-4}}$$
$\ce{[OH^-]}={10^{-2}}$ Which corresponds to $\ce{pOH = 2}$ or $\ce{pH = 12}$

Comment: Re: *The equilibrium expression must be solved as a quadratic* yes and no. It depends on the precision of the answer. Little of the carbonate goes to bicarbonate, so to two significant figures you really don't need the quadratic solution. $$\sqrt{(2\times10^{-4})\times 0.5} = 0.010$$ so that solution is off by about 1 part in 50. Seems good enough.

Comment: @MaxW I edit my answer your comment makes the calculation easy

Comment: Making the calculations easy is the point. In reality I'd be surprised if the "true" value was within 5% of the calculation. Also the "exact" solution, neglecting activities, is a cubic equation. So even the quadratic is an approximation.